# Stop Website Directory Listing

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, web-applications

I have a small annoyance with the website I'm developing(in Codeigniter) - when the website isn't cached in my browser and I connect to it , for a second or two I see a directory listing of my root (after 1-2 seconds the listing stops and the website displays ok).

I've read that I can try to prevent this with .htaccess files so I have this written in the first line  -

```
IndexIgnore *
```

But it doesn't help . 
Any advice ?

Comment: This should not happen as index.php file is read and executed. The problem must be with your server.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to disable directory index is doing the following in a `.htaccess` file

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: How does this fit with the OP saying that it shows up briefly and then disappears?

Comment: It is perhaps a byproduct of an incorrectly configured Options parameter. It's worth doing correctly to see if the problem persists then addressing the brief appearance problem if it continues

Answer (score 1):

try this `Options -Indexes` in .htaccess,